# Unable to see Collector component in Graylog Web UI in Ubuntu

Tags: graylog2

I have followed the exact steps mentioned [here](http://docs.graylog.org/en/1.0/pages/installation.html#operating-system-packages) for Ubuntu 14.0.4. I've got the mongodb,elastic search,graylog server/web/collector up. Unfortunately when I hit the web ui http://:9000 and login through the admin, I am unable to see the collector component all together. I'm attaching the screenshot of the System tab. What am I missing? [image]

Answer (score 0):

The latest repository they had, was installing an older version of the server, which didn't support the collector functionality. I had manually downloaded the tar files, and it worked.